# When the function runs multiple times, the list is nested in the default parameter, but the integer is not

Tags: python, default-parameters

The list, `x`, isn't initialized to the parameter default value each time the function is operated, but remains in the previous state and adds a new value.
That's how the function was executed 5 times, so it became `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]`.
However, the integer y appears to hold the default value. It has been run 5 times, but it continues to output `2`.
Why does `y` finally output `2` instead of `6` when the function is executed 5 times?

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), but it explains where the list binds to a function. But I wonder why the principle does not apply to integer default parameters.

```py
def foo(x=[],y=1):
    x.append(7)
    y += 1
    return x, y

print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
```

```py
([7], 2)
([7, 7], 2)
([7, 7, 7], 2)
([7, 7, 7, 7], 2)
([7, 7, 7, 7, 7], 2)
```

Comment: *"I've already read this question ... But I wonder why the principle does not apply to integer default parameters."* Well that means you didn't read it carefully. It was just 5 mins ago and your question was closed with this duplicate and you are asking the same question again...

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the repeated questions. And it's true that I didn't read the text in detail. Actually, I tried to read it carefully, but the answers felt too difficult because I was a beginner.. But I was so curious that I was sad that the question was closed. I think I was too hasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int's are immutable, lists are not. When you assign a default value to a parameter you are assigning a reference to that value. Performing `y += 1` actually creates a new reference and  assigns it to `y`, it does not change the value of the old reference. When you mutate the container you are not changing the reference. Example:

```
y = 1
x = y

# This will be true as they have the same reference
print(x is y)  #  True

y += 1
# This will be false as the reference to y has been changed
print(x is y)  #  False
```

```
y = []
x = y

# This will be true as they have the same reference
print(x is y)  #  True

y.append(1)
# This will still be true, the reference to the container remains the same.
print(x is y)  #  True
```